# Challenge: Solve $x^x = \frac{1}{256}$ without the use of the Lambert W function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, exponentiation

As stated above: $x^x = \frac{1}{256}$, solve for $x$.

Since $256$ is power of $2$, I let $x = 2^n$, where $n \in R$.

So:

- $2^{n^{(2^n)}} = 2^{-8}$
- $n*2^n = -8$
- $-n = 2^{3-n}$
- $\log_2$$(-n) = 3-n$
- $\log_2$$((-n)^{\frac{1}{3-n}}) =1$
- $(-n)^{\frac{1}{3-n}}= 2$

I am currently stuck at this point with no idea on how I should progress forward. My last option is to solve it numerically but I would like to see if there are any other algebraic ways(other than Lambert W function).

Comment: Note that the function $x^x$ has a global minimum at $x=1/e$ with the value $e^{-1/e}$ which is greater than 1/256. Hence $x^x = 1/256$ cannot have a real-valued solution. Are you sure you are supposed to find a complex solution by hand, without the Lambert W function?

Comment: @Florian that's not quite right – we can also consider $x<0$ with $x$ an integer – running through the possibilites yields $x=-4$ as a solution.

Comment: @robbie, yeah I was just wondering how to get there in a different way than looking and seeing it.

Comment: @Robbie yes, I just checked and $x= -4$ is a solution, but however, my method would not work; $2^n \not= -4$ for $n \in R$. Unless, of course, we start talking about complex values.

Comment: As soon as you know that $x<0$ is necessary for a real solution, then $x\in\mathbb Z$. $|x^x| \leq 5^{-5} < \frac{1}{256}$ for $x\leq -5$, so we only need to check up to $-4$. So it is deductive, but I admit the method could be a little hard to see if you didn't know what you were looking for...

Comment: You want a solution to $y^y=256$ where $y$ is an even non-negative integer and then $x=-y$.

Comment: Gosh, how could I forget about the negative integers. Of course, so simple. @Robbie: I guess your comment should be an answer maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to condense comments into an answer:

We seek real solutions for $x$. Let $f(x) = x^x$. Note that $f$ is defined on $\{x > 0\} \cup \{x \in \mathbb{Z}: x < 0\}$.

For $x>0$, by differentiation we can show $f\vert_{x>0}$ has a global minimum at $x = \frac 1 e > \frac{1}{256}$. So $f(x) = \frac{1}{256}$ has no solutions for $x>0$.

Now consider $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{<0}$. Note that $f$ is strictly increasing on this domain, so there is at most one solution. Beginning at $-1$ and descending in steps of $1$, we can find the solution $x=-4$.

(We could have "spotted" $-4$ as well, but this method generalises to other equations $f(x) = y$ where $y \in (0, \frac 1 e]$, either providing a unique solution or the absence of a solution.)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now :)